# Getting phone number in inbox/outbox

Tags: android

I am currently using

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
Cursor messagesCursor = cr.query(uri, new String[] { "_id", "address", "body", "person" }, null, null, null);

if (messagesCursor.getCount() > 0) {
    while (messagesCursor.moveToNext()) {
        colName = getContactName(messagesCursor.getString(messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("address"))) + "\n";
    }
}
```

to get all the text in the user's inbox. From there, `messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("address")` will get the SMS's number. Then it will be place in `getContactName()` where it will then get the contacts' name from their contact's list.

This method will take a long time as it goes though EVERY SINGLE text message, get number, then get the contact's name, check if name exist in array, if it doesn't put in array then from there create a ListView.

The app will take a long time to load on start up if the user's inbox contains lots of text.

Is there any special way to get UNIQUE numbers from inbox? Something in `cr.query`?

Thanks in advance.(:

---

**EDIT :**

I'm creating just a simple inbox application. It reads from the original inbox message and list the messages in it.

For this project, what I did was to read through ALL the "address" which is the phone number, put it in an ArrayList, and finally to the ListView. As it cycles through all the messages in inbox, it takes a long time to startup.

For example :

*Inbox Messages*

- Person 1

  Person 1

  Person 1

  Person 2

  Person 2

  Person 3

  Person 3

  Person 3

  Person 3

---

**What my current code does :**

Read EVERY SINGLE message

Check if name in ArrayList

If it is, skip. If not, add in array.

Throw ArrayList into ListView.

---

**What my intention was :**

A code that only reads out :

Person 1

Person 2

Person 3

Answer (score 0):

Try only using "address" in projection (that means, don't include even "_id") - I'm not sure about this but it may solve the case.

Comment: It's just the query and needed in that query to get the sms. I need a query like `UNIQUE` or `DISTINCT`. Do you know how to? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Afaik `UNIQUE` or `DISTINCT` are not allowed as long as you're using `ContentProvider` (you could open the db file directly but that would be a dirty hack as there's no guarantee it has the same path on all devices). Can you clarify the scenario you're willing to implement? There's a solid chance we'll come up with a way of doing it without using `UNIQUE`

Comment: I've edited and explained my intention on the first post. Hopefully you get what I mean. Thanks in advance for helping me! Appreciate it.(:

Comment: Hang on, I've got a lot on my plate right now, I'll get back and take a look at it later.

Comment: @IvanBartsov I've been waiting for over a year Ivan!